# How to Add React Js On an Existing Website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

So reactjs.org has an excellent tutorial on how to add react js to an existing website [HERE](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) by adding react js code as scripts. That is working well for me. My doubt is that how would we work with components that we download from npm?(eg: react-router, react-bootstrap,etc.) Usually when we work on a complete react project we just install them with npm and import them in react js, but how do we install such components or get their script files like we got react script files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can add those library using `<script>` as well.
react-router: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router/umd/react-router.min.js"></script>`

react-bootstrap: `<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
  crossorigin
/>`

check the documentation for corresponding library.

Answer (score 16):

The process would be similar to the process described on the React site. In their example, they implement a simple single-component (`<LikeButton />`) application with no external dependencies. To use external components/modules you would need to either bundle them into your app, or load them as scripts.

**Preferred Method**

The preferred method would be to use a bundler like webpack, parcel, or similar to bundle your code and modules into a single script.

1. Create your `app.js` file, using `import`s to load external components

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

   const LittleApp = () => (
     <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
       Hello World
     </Button>
   );

   ReactDOM.render(<LittleApp />, document.getElementById("littleApp"));
   ```
2. Use webpack, parcel, or similar to bundle the `app.js` into a single `bundled.js` file
3. Load the `bundled.js` file into your page

**Alternate Method**

It's also possible to load certain components using Universal Module Definition (UMD) files in `<script>` tags. This could work for a simple add-on app, but probably not recommended in most cases. I tend to use these only when prototyping ideas, or demoing solutions on Stack Overflow.

Something like this:

```js
const LittleApp = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MaterialUI.Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Hello World
      </MaterialUI.Button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<LittleApp />, document.getElementById("littleApp"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>

<div id="littleApp"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Brett, where I can find resources on bundling my app.js and all the imported js files into one file to be imported as an src by a simple html page?

Comment: The Create React App (CRA) https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app is probably the easiest way to get started. It uses webpack under the hood. Once you've installed CRA and created a project, it allows you to run `npm run build` to bundle your scripts into a single `.js` file, which you would then load into a `<script>` tag on your site.

Comment: but npm run build chunks everything into different js files right? How to get it to bundle to single js file?

Comment: Depends on the webpack config. It can bundle everything into a single chunk.

Comment: can you please provide me with a resource where I can accomplish this? I really want to integrate this page with my existing application.

Comment: You can accomplish the same by including the various chunks, just add `<script>` tags for each chunk. I'm not sure the configuration can be changed to output a single chunk with CRA. You might need to run `npm run eject` to get full control over the webpack configuration.

Answer (score 1):

https://cdnjs.com/ hosts many FOSS (Free and Open-Source Software) web libraries. Searching `react-router` yields links to development and minified versions you can use in your applications. But much like [klugjo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57093445/11802655), I would highly advise against this, and manage your project's modules with npm if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use Babel to include your components with JSX.
Only 3 steps:

1. Add React library
2. Add Babel
3. Add to all scripts with JSX `type="text/babel"`

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="react">Component is loading</div>

<script type="text/babel">
class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h2>Hi, this is the React component!</h2>;
  }
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#react'));
root.render(<Test />);
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

I would highly recommend against that and go the standard route:

- Use [create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/) to create a full fledged react app
- Install your modules using npm
- Code your app
- Build the app and deploy the resulting bundle (create-react-app provides all the tools you need for that)

Fetching react from a CDN like in the link you have provided is suitable for a quick Proof of concept but not for a production app

Comment: I know this is definitely better, but how can I do that when most of my website is built using some other JS library and I only need react for a standalone page?

Comment: that creates a SPA (single page application); the OP was explicitly asking how to create a reactjs app on an existing website. this answer is not a suitable one.